# Select Distinct query

Tags: sql-server

I want to retrieve data in the format:

```
Category, Question, Status, Answer
```

I dont want any repetition so I retrieved unique Category, Question & Status by:

```
select distinct category, question, status
from sharepoint_vw
```

However I want to have an additional column as 'Answer' to be a % value calculated by the expression:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Status.Value="Unfavourable",1,0))/COUNT(Fields!Status.Value)
```

I just dont know how to convert this expression into SQL and combine it with the select distinct query to get the results I need.

Comment: It seems like you are mixing SQL Server and Reporting Services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want Status as part of the output from the SQL, then you will have to aggregate your total count for each `category, question` in a subquery. Then you can use that total in your calculations in your main query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  sharepoint_vw.category,
  sharepoint_vw.question,
  sharepoint_vw.status,
  count(*)/total.rcount as answer
FROM sharepoint_vw
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
       SELECT 
         category, 
         question,          
         CAST(COUNT(*) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) as rcount 
       FROM sharepoint_vw 
       GROUP BY category, question
     ) as total
       ON sharepoint_vw.category = total.category
         AND sharepoint_vw.question = total.question
GROUP BY 
  sharepoint_vw.category,
  sharepoint_vw.question,
  sharepoint_vw.status,
  total.rcount
```

That `answer` columns will hold the percentage total for each `status` now. You can see this in action at [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/42b28/12)

Something worth mentioning is that we are dealing with integers here (sums of counts) So we will have to cast at least one of these to a `Decimal()` type otherwise you'll just get an integer return.

Comment: Sorry I think this does work however I forgot to mention theres a Year column in the database so the count should be only where Year = '2018', can you advise please thanks a lot

Comment: Just add a `WHERE Year = '2018' before each GROUP BY (in the subquery and main query).

Comment: Thanks just did it all working perfectly. Thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
select category, question
avg(case status when 'unfavorable' then 1.0 else 0.0 end) as avgunfavorable
from sharepoint_vw
group by  category, question
```

Comment: Thanks but avgunfavorable is not coming out with decimals like I expected, they are all coming out as 1?

Comment: I changed the query.  check it out